# Autoit get current caret position Or current text box position

Tags: autoit

So i am working on a project and i got stuck on this part.
I am trying to locate the position of ether the typing caret(The blinking line while typing) or the current text box that is being typed in.

The main part that is hard is i am looking to do this for every input on my computer (Firefox search, Notepad, Renaming files, writing this post...)

I am beginning to doubt that auto-it can do this, i am open to using another language that can do this. (I have not checked any other language but Auto-it yet)

I have tested "WinGetCaretPos()" and a few other random scripts, but they had the same problem, they don't return the correct position.

~Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all controls are standard window controls that can be accessed with AutoIt functions. Many programs (especially browsers) have nonstandard controls so "every input" on the computer might be hard to get.

Here is an example of how to get the control information of any active window that is giving focus to a control AND has standard windows controls.

```
HotKeySet("{ESC}", "Terminate")

While 1
    Sleep(500)
    GetControlFocus()
WEnd

Func GetControlFocus()
    Local $hWinHandle = WinGetHandle("[Active]")
    Local $sControl = ControlGetFocus($hWinHandle)

    Local $sText = "The active window handle is: " & $hWinHandle & @CRLF

    If $sControl <> "" Then
        $sText &= "The control with focus in the active window is: " & $sControl & @CRLF
        Local $aPos = ControlGetPos($hWinHandle, "", $sControl)
        $sText &= "Mouse position: X: " & $aPos[0] & " Y: " & $aPos[1] & @CRLF & "Size: " & $aPos[2] & ", " & $aPos[3]

    Else
        $sText &= "The active window is not giving focus to a control that AutoIt recognizes."
    EndIf

    ToolTip($sText, 0, 0)
EndFunc   ;==>GetControlFocus

Func Terminate()
    Exit
EndFunc   ;==>Terminate
```

You can get the control position of other programs using IUIAutomation and this [UDF](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/153520-iuiautomation-ms-framework-automate-chrome-ff-ie/). But it would not be as simple as using a few standard AutoIt functions.

Comment: Thanks for you help, that is a useful script. I have done some more research and i have come to the conclusion that this approach is not going to work no matter what language i use.